# React-native fontFamily is not working as it should

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use the custom font called times-news-roman.

I created react-native.config.js file, here is what's inside of it

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {}, // grouped into "project"
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'], // stays the same
};
```

I also created my assets folder in the root of the app.
[image]

I am trying to use this custom font like this:

```
headerTextLight: {
color: 'black',
fontWeight: 'bold',
fontSize: 30,
paddingLeft: 10,
paddingTop: 10,
fontFamily: 'times-new-roman',
 },
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Unrecognized font family 'times-new-roman'
```

[image]

I am using     `"react-native": "^0.63.3"`. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you run `react-native link` after this? also make sure font files are created in respected android and iOS folders (**assets/font** for android and for iOS **info.plist**). for more info see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60XGVZffPeE) video.

Comment: Thank you for the informations, Yes I ran react-native link and after that I could not even run the app anymore,I am trying to find the solution now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your fonts are included in your bundled resources within the Build Phases section

[image]

Add your fonts to the Info.plist

[image]

Within your project folder navigate to the Info.plist file where you will want to add your fonts. Hover on the last line in the list and click on the plus sign to add a new line. Select the option “Fonts provided by application.” Now you will add all your fonts and make sure the string is EXACTLY THE SAME as the font file (.otf, .ttf) name.